# Web Services in old JBoss 3.2.3.GA

Tags: jboss

We have an old JBoss 3.2.3 server which hosted an application and exposed EJBs for remote access.

This application has only received minor maintenance in years, and we did not put some effort to migrate it to newer releases of the app server.

Now, we are integrating it with another application, and we have a requirement to also expose SOAP Web Services.

At first, I wasn't worried, since JBoss 3.2.3 announces compliance with the J2EE 1.4 spec ([JSR151](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=151)), which specifies the APIs for web services: web services ([JSR109](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=109)) and JAXRPC ([JSR101](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=101)).

However, my first deploy using the JAX-RPC api *failed*, because JBoss did not find the JAX-RPC classes.

So my questions are:

- Is JBoss 3.2.3 really a J2EE 1.4 app server ? The lack of JAX-RPC classes seem to indicate otherwise.
- What are the APIs for **exposing** a web services in JBoss 3.2.3 ?
- What are the APIs for **consuming** a web services from an EJB deployed in JBoss 3.2.3 ?

In the end, I can always deploy additional APIs and libraries with my application, but I'd like to avoid overlapping existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss 3.2.3.GA is **not** a fully compliant J2EE 1.4 server. For instance, it does not implement the EJB 2.1 interface, only EJB 2.0 [[1](https://community.jboss.org/message/109979#109979)].

Also, JBoss 4.0 [announces being the first J2EE 1.4 compliant server](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/whatsnew40/html/#j2ee); I conclude that JBoss.org did not certify JBoss 3.2.3 as compliant.

Even though not-compliant, JBoss 3.2.3 has some features for consuming SOAP Web-Services. For instance, it ships with Apache Axis 1.1 and JAX-RPC apis, so one can easily generate java classes for a WS client outside the server and have them run in an enterprise app.

Exposing web services is a more difficult task. One way of exposing web services is to [create a Stateless EJB and expose it as a webservice endpoint](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html/Server_Configuration_Guide/Web_Services-EJB_Endpoints.html). However, that's part of the EJB2.1 spec, which is not available in 3.2.3.

Too bad ! In the end, we will look for other alternatives in exposing our web services.

The newer JavaEE specs and servers are so much easier to develop for. It's the old specs and servers that gave JavaEE a bad rep.